# Regarding Spring mail API

Tags: spring, jakarta-mail

In my project there is a requirement to create a job which will send multiple emails.. I was thinking to use Spring mail API. I checked there is a method

```
send(MimeMessage[] mimeMessages)
```

Which will send emails in batch, I have a question, if any of the mail failed while sending, will the whole job fails or rest of them will be sent? Is it possible to get a result that which one is successful and which one failed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context-support/src/main/java/org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSenderImpl.java.

Messages are sent individually and the `send(MimeMessage[])` method throws `MailSendException` which contains the messages that failed to go.